# How to pass configuration flags to nginx-ingress in minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress

To use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough` annotation I need to be [`starting the controller with the --enable-ssl-passthrough flag.`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#ssl-passthrough)

How do I pass that flag if I start the ingress with `minikube addons enable ingress`?

I tried `minikube addons enable ingress --enable-ssl-passthrough` and got `Error: unknown flag: --enable-ssl-passthrough`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an easy way to change it. But you can always manually change the ingress controller deployment object so that it passes the arguments that you need. For example, [in this repository](https://github.com/ajanthan/minikube-ingress-with-ssl-passthrough/) someone has the Kubernetes manifests for the minikube ingress addon.

[If you take a look](https://github.com/ajanthan/minikube-ingress-with-ssl-passthrough/blob/3969487fc08dad5a2638afe7c9e238ca02875083/ingress-dp.yaml#L131), this is where the `--enable-ssl-passthrough` option is passed to the ingress controller. You just need to update your Deployment the same way.

I believe that minikube installs the ingress controller deployment on the `kube-system` namespace, so try listing the deployments there using `kubectl -n kube-system get deployments`. And update the right deployment object using `kubectl -n kube-system edit deployments <ingress-deployment-name>`, changing `ingress-deployment-name` with whatever name it's using on your case.

Comment: Do I need to do anything besides `kubectl -n kube-system edit deployments <ingress-deployment-name>`? After I edit it, for some short time I can see my changes whe doing `kubectl -n kube-system describe deployments <ingress-deployment-name`, but then it gets back to the initial state.

Comment: Hi, @[Kirill Kliushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5617137/kirill-kliushkin), did you create new one deployment or did you change the existing one (default)?

Comment: Maybe minikube is replacing your changes. Then you will need to copy the modified Kubernetes deployment manifests to `~/.minikube/addons` location and restart Minikube

Answer (score 2):

After enabling the ingress addons:

```
$ minikube addons enable ingress
```

Add the `--enable-ssl-passthrough` option:

```
$ minikube kubectl -- patch deployment -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/args/-", "value":"--enable-ssl-passthrough"}]'
```

For further details see the Kubernetes documentation https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough